# Get reference to form from unhandled exception

Tags: c#, exception

I have a global exception handler in program.cs to catch unhandled exceptions.

```
Unhandled Exception: 
Sender: System.Threading.Thread
Sender Type: System.Threading.Thread
Source: AssetManager.Library.Common
```

Is it possible to get a reference to the form that generated the unhandled exception?

Comment: Do you see your form in the StackTrace of the Exception?

Comment: No, unless the exception passes the form reference in the exception object.  Which doesn't happen in any of the standard framework exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An exception also provide the stack trace for the scope of the exception. If the form that you are referring to is in the scope, you can see the details of the form in the stack trace as well.

Comment: I've decided to keep a reference myself to the active form